# What loads faster: a large executable, or a small executable that requires many other modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, bundle, rollupjs

Case study: does my node (server) application load faster if I bundle `lodash` with it, which results in an executable in the order of megabytes? Or does the application load faster if I let lodash outside of the bundle and just `require` it at run time? This way my executable is only a few kilobytes, but the whole application is much larger because I need to ship it with the whole lodash library

Reducing the size of an application is in general a good thing, but I don't want to do it at the expense of a slower run time.

I appreciate any pointers on this topic. Also let me know if the question is not clear enough. Cheers!

(`lodash` is just an example, I could have picked any large library)

Comment: A server application shouldn't be (re)starting that many times; startup time should be all but irrelevant. In general, you don't need to use a bundler for a server-side app (aside from maybe serverless solutions such as Lambda/Cloud Run) anyway.

Comment: Secondly: why don't you measure this? Try both approaches, e.g. benchmark how long it takes in total for your app to first start up, then successfully serve e.g. 10,000 requests.

Comment: Hi @AKX, the whole application is running either in AWS lambdas, or in containers... startup matters in my use case :) Benchmarking is my next approach, but I still would like what makes an application start up faster or slower. I lack the necessary JS module system knowledge to asses it myself :/

Comment: Well, intuitively it sounds like it should be faster to load everything from a single bundled file rather than resolve require() paths.